# How to create multiple flavors apks with single keystore android

Tags: android, gradle

I am working on android application,application is having 40 flavors,i configured all these flavors with different conditions,i wanted to use same keystore for all these 40 flavors applications or should i create seperate keystore for every flavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a single signing config and share it between the flavors:

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
    release {
      storeFile file('your.keystore')
      storePassword "password"
      keyAlias "alias"
      keyPassword "password"
    }
  }

  productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    flavor2 {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: if i run gradle assemble release will it generate apks for all flavors

Comment: Is this a question? If it is - then yes, Gradle will build all release variants for all flavors.